# CraftCMS 3.6.4 - 503 Error when logged out of control panel

Tags: craftcms

Getting a 503 Service Unavailable when trying to access the site (both local and remote) only when I'm *not* logged in to the control panel.

The error appears to stem from `vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php` line 63:

```
 protected $allowAnonymous = self::ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_NEVER;
```

On line 152 the code checks the value of `$allowAnonymous`:

```
   if (!($test & $allowAnonymous)) {
```

And on line 165 inside the `if` block, it throws an exception:

```
  throw new ServiceUnavailableHttpException();
```

How do I tell Craft to always allow guests access to the site? And why is it not the default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `config/general.php` add:

```
 'isSystemLive' => true
```